# Slowly fade away image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I used the [Draw Worm](https://gist.github.com/xav76/3940912) and made some changes and the result was [this](http://filart.esy.es/footer/), but I have a problem to solve. I want to make the lines that have been there a long time to slowly fade away into darkness. I made this code:

```
function fadeOut() {
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    setTimeout(fadeOut,10000);
}
fadeOut();
```

The problem is that the lines are disappearing too quickly, instead I wanted to obtain a gradual fade out, or more slowly.

Comment: You can't erase the lines that you've already drawn on the canvas. But you can clear the canvas area on two specified coordinates if you have stored the locations of those drawn lines.

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy. The problem is that `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` means fully opaque black. You will probably want to try some semitransparent color. For example:

```
function fadeOut() {
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    setTimeout(fadeOut,1000);
}
fadeOut();
```

I also recommend using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`. I made a fiddle of your code, look how much nicer it is with fast animation: https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/mwj60hq4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was and it was very simple for you :))). One more question, there is any way when I load the page instead of one self drawing line have multiple lines? Thanks.

Comment: @OvidiuOvi I don't understand your second question. But if you have more questions, you should post them using the "Ask question" button. Comments are not supposed to be used for asking questions, they are for asking for clarification or pointing out errors.

Comment: Sorry and I didn't knew that rule. Thanks for the help and it very beautiful with the fast animation too. Also i added the  requestAnimationFrame function instead of seTimeout. My question was about the same code and was if there anyway to obtain at the beginning of animation instead of one line that is self drawing at the bottom page, multiple lines in different places. Thanks!

Comment: @OvidiuOvi If your problem is solved, you can mark the answer as accepted. This will save other people's time because they will see this question is solved already.